# Broke into Vs. Broke to Vs. Broke in.

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

Is there any difference in meaning, among the following sentences, different from each others in preposition.

> - The jug broke **into** pieces.
> - The jug broke **to** pieces.
> - The jug broke **in** pieces.

And are all of them grammatically correct?

Comment: Why don't you google them first or put them into a grammar checker, of which there are many on the internet?

Comment: I already looked them up, but unfortunately I didn’t see any difference  among them. @Lambie

Comment: Ok, the correct one is ***break  into pieces***. The others are incorrect. :)

Comment: All three are used, and mean the same thing. Some speakers might understand **to** and **into** as referring to the becoming state and **in** as referring to the resultant state.

Comment: All three are not used. Things like ***glasses etc.  break into pieces***, in standard English. However, ***a person can break something to pieces***, that yes. So, a jug breaks into pieces, a person breaks something to pieces but neither breaks in pieces. He was in pieces when his girlfriend broke up with him.